# Generic Type in Maps

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a JavaScript Map and I am struggling with the correct Type definition. My values are objects with contain the two properties `target` and `propertyName` and I don't want to loose the type safety for this by using any. This is what I've guessed (which is not valid syntax):

```
type MetaDataType = { target: Function, propertyName: string };
private _getMetaDataCache: Map<Function, <T extends MetaDataType>[]> = new Map();
```

**So how would I properly create a Map with generic types in Typescript?**

Comment: What's wrong with just `Map<Function, MetaDataType>`?

Comment: I believe that this would force my Objects to exactly contain these properties. However I want to store objects which contain these properties AND potentially other properties (which would be a conflict)

Comment: Agree with @jcalz, according to your definition - no need in generics. It is fine if object will have additional properties.

Comment: I think you guys are right, it requires a Casting from IMetaData to the generic Type when I want to return it as generic type though. I should have provided more code of my use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
  type MetaDataType = { target: Function, propertyName: string };
  type generic = <T extends MetaDataType[]> (args: T) => T;
  private _getMetaDataCache: Map<Function, generic[]> = new Map<Function, generic[]>();
```

See the section about [Generic Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: The TS compiler says `[ts]
Type 'Map<{}, {}>' is not assignable to type '<T extends MetaDataType[]>(arg: Map<Function, T[]>) => T'.
  Type 'Map<{}, {}>' provides no match for the signature '<T extends MetaDataType[]>(arg: Map<Function, T[]>): T'.`

Comment: This is no generic type, but I definetely need a generic type.